# Errors after migration of ee 2.9.3 to new host

Tags: migration, server-migration

I have imported the database and all website files to my inmotionhosting.com VPS hosting environment via FTP.

I have followed steps #7 and #8 as seen in the migration guide:
http://216.243.142.229/rick/user_guide/operations/moving.html

but run into the following error:

> The following tag has a syntax error:
>
> {exp:strip_html}
>
> Please correct the syntax in your template.

when I attempt to view the new website environment here: http://198.46.84.39/~steame6/

I'm unsure how to proceed.  Can anyone advise?

Answer (score 0):

`{exp:strip_html}` is a tag from an EE2 add-on that is now [discontinued](https://devot-ee.com/add-ons/strip_html).

I'm guessing you haven't migrated the addon to the new host.

When EE reaches a tag associated with `{exp:strip_html}` it looks for an add-on but doesn't find one, and throws the error...

So to complete the migration you will need to remove the calls to this tag, or install the copy from the old host.

Depends what you are trying to do in the template, but you can strip HTML from text quite well / flexibly with other current / not discontinued addons.  My preference is [streeng](https://github.com/caddis/streeng) by there are others.

HTH